# PHP MySql user account bypassing cookies

Tags: php, mysql, post, cookies, authentication

Right, I've been tinkering with this for a while and got it all to work except for the user account page, my question is; can anybody spot on typos I have made here or give me a little help in making it work?

The website seems to bypass this part and go straight to the else (shown below):

```
<?
                if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])){
                    $email = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
                    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
                    $con = mysqli_connect(DATABASE STUFF) or die(mysqli_error());
                    $check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email, pass2 FROM userAccount WHERE email=$email")or die(mysqli_error()); 

                    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){ 
                        if ($pass != $info['pass2']){
                            echo "Wrong Password or Email!, Please <a href='login.php'>Login here</a> to see your account or <a href='register.php'>Register here</a>.";
                        }else{
                            $con=mysqli_connect(DATABASE STUFF);
                            $sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM userAccount WHERE email=$email)";

                            $query = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
                            $column = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

                            echo "<section class='userName'><h3>".$column['firstName']." ".$column['surname']."</h3></section>";
                            echo "<section class='address'>".$column['addressLine1']."<br />".$column['addressLine2']."<br />".$column['county']."<br />".$column['country']."<br />".$column['postCode']."</section>";
                            echo "<section class='email'><h3>".$column['email']."</h3></section>";
                            echo "<section class='passwordUpdate'><a href='update.php?user_id=".$column['user_id']."'>Change Password</a></section>";
                        } 
                    }
```

The 'else' that it goes straight to no matter what:

```
                }else{
                    echo "You cannot see this page, Please <a href='login.php'>Login here</a> to see your account or <a href='register.php'>Register here</a>.";
                }
```

Below is the login process, just in case anyone asks:

```
<?

$con = mysqli_connect(DATABASE STUFF) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])){ 
$email = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 
$pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email, pass2 FROM userAccount WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'")or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){
    if ($pass != $info['pass2']){
    }else{
        header("Location: http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/userAccount.php");
    }
}
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(!$_POST['email'] | !$_POST['pass']) {
    die('You did not fill in a required field.');
}

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
}

if(IsInjected($email)){
    die('Bad email value!');
}

$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userAccount WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$check2 = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if ($check2 == 0) {
    die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href="http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/registration.php">Register</a>');
}

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){
    $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
    $info['pass2'] = stripslashes($info['pass2']);
    $_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);

    if($_POST['pass'] != $info['pass2']) {
        die('Incorrect password, please <a href="http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/login.php">try again</a>.');
    }else{
        $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $hour = time() + 3600;
        setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['email'], $hour); 
        setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['pass'], $hour);   
        header("Location: http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/userAccount.php"); 
    }
}
}else{
header("Location: http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/pages/login.php");
} 

function IsInjected($str){
$injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)');
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

and the login form in the PHP file:

```
            <form action="extras/loginProcess.php" method="post" name="login_form">
                Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in" />
            </form>
```

Finally the TABLE in MyPHPAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE `userAccount` (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstName` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `surname` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `addressLine1` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `addressLine2` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `county` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `country` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `postCode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `pass` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `pass2` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

The database is correct and I have tried my hardest to make this work, kept going back to the default code where I know it works mostly to be safe.

I have already tried changing the pass2 for pass (even changing pass in the database to password and configuring where needed but the same happens).

If anyone can help me this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Passwords and cookies, much like fire and water, don't mix.

Comment: should I really be using sessions for this, its for a an ecommerce site.

Comment: Considered putting the data into a session instead? Much easier to keep track of and much more secure

Comment: @Machavity I am starting to think about it now yea haha, right now I just want to get this working and then adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's always good to learn writing some own stuff.. but why don't you use some existing platform for this like wordpress, drupal, etc. that have built-in login system?

You code is extremely vulnerable to attacks. I could write any SQL to my cookies and you add that variable right to SQL query ($email variable).

Comment: I'm new to this still and am learning, i'd rather not use a platform as of the moment and keep learning to code my own before I go onto something else.

I know it is vulnerable, I'm trying to get it to work before I implement anything else.

"I could write any SQL to my cookies and you add that variable to SQL query ($email variable)."I do not understand what you mean sorry.

Comment: Ok, i recommend to learn drupal.. you also learn php but don't have to code all of the things.. for the sql part check this link..
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thank you, I'll start with that then, and thank you for the link